# Where can I found XML documentation for Windows.winmd library?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

In Windows Store apps, either for Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 8.1 the core metadata file containing all wrapper methods for accessing Windows Runtime API is **Windows.winmd**.

The question I have is, **where is the location of the related XML documentation file**, which is generated when building your own library in visual Studio, or in which file is stored the annotation of this Windows runtime library? I've searched in various SDK locations on my PC but found only plain winmd files.

Thanks

Comment: Same directory where Windows.winmd is stored.  C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.xml on most programmer's machines right now.  You are not supposed to be interested in that, don't copy it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing one tool for generating HTML doc from XML comments and I wanted to test it on Windows.xml. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.